# C++ template and ODR Rule

Tags: c++

Why does following works in `C++`, I thought `ODR` rule will come into picture for following code

```
typedef char      int8; 
class Sample {
public:
  template <typename T>
  void test( T param){
  }
};

int main() {
  Sample s;
  s.test<char>('a');
  s.test<int8>((int8)'b');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong? what do you think would be the correct behaviour?

Comment: Why? There's just one instantiation, of `void test(char param);`

Comment: @jrok : But will compiler not generate two version of test function

Comment: No, typedef is just another name for the same type.

Comment: There is only one version. You can easily test this: http://ideone.com/1K6wg

Comment: If int8 is the same as char, there is only one definition and instantiation. Where is the violation of ODR? If int8 is different from char, then there are two different instantiations. Where is the violation of ODR then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the template instantiations are done and compiler gets rid of typedefs and unnecessary casts, your code is exactly the same as:

```
class Sample {
public:
  void test(char param){
  }
};

int main() {
  Sample s;
  s.test('a');
  s.test('b');
  return 0;
}
```

You seem to think that a `typedef` declares another distinct type, but that's not the case. It's just an alias (for your convinience, usually). OTOH, when you call a function template with a different template parameter, functions with different signatures are generated. No ODR violation in either case.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing the same thing both times. It just looks like they're different.

The first one says it'll use the `char` version, so T becomes a `char`.

The second says it'll use the `int8` version, so T would become an `int8`, which is actually just a `char` in disguise. Therefore, T will still be a char, and you're passing in a char in both cases, so all is well.