# overloading for typedef parameters

Tags: c++, typedef, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading member methods with typedef aliases as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582519/overloading-member-methods-with-typedef-aliases-as-parameters)

I have following method 
`void setField(char x);` and another overloaded methoed `void setField(int8_t x);`
This get compiled on all platform other than `solaris`, on `solaris` `int8_t` is `typedef as char`

Is there any way to resolve this issue, as I do not want to change the name of the `method`
I get compiler error saying that `method already exists`

Comment: I know there's a question just like this with an answer out there.

Comment: @chris : Which question, could you please tell

Comment: I'm not sure. I just remember seeing something strikingly similar today. I'm trying to find it.

Comment: @chris maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583085/c-template-and-odr-rule).

Comment: @juanchopanza, I think there was one even just before that.

Comment: @juanchopanza: not it is not same, I cannot use template as behavior is different for the method

Comment: Could you define the problematic function inside a preprocessor `#ifdef`, and define differently if the platform is Solaris?

Comment: @iammilind, exactly the one I was thinking of, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no way to resolve this. A typedef is just another name for the same type. But you can only overload on different types. So in your case - the compiler sees to setField(char x).

Why do you need those 2 methods? Since sizeof(char) is 1 according to the standard, there's really no difference between those names.

Comment: Because on other platform it is defined as unsigned char and getting compiled.

Comment: int8_t is signed. so what are you doing?

Comment: @Avinash this kind of problem is exactly why `stdint.h` was introduced. If your code relies on strict and consistent definitions of signedness and size of integer types, you should use this file. Other than that, you cannot untypedef something in C.

Comment: again my question - why do you need this?

Comment: @TobiasLangner maybe a very localized, but very pertinent example: did you ever try to `std::cout` an `int8_t`? It doesn't work, cause it's the same as a char, but with a very different meaning. Strong typedefs would be nice to have for sure.

Comment: yes, std::cout<<static_cast<int>(int8_t_var)<<std::endl; That's what you get if want the performance of primitives.

Comment: The "Possible Duplicate gives the best answer to this.

Comment: Also, to the "why", (and admittedly expand the scope of the OP question) there are actually platforms which are non conforming to the standard that create problems. The "proper" way is to only define stdint.h types that are exactly correct, for which int8_t should not even be defined.  For example there are some architectures which have 32 bit sizes for chars.  For such platforms, non-conforming toolchains have been known to go ahead and define int8_t, even though they really should only define int_least8_t.  In any case, these all provide problems for C++ overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognise int_8. stdint.h has int8_t. Have you tried that? otherwise, find the header file on Solaris that defines int_8 and conditionally exclude it on a Solaris build using the appropriate preprocessor define.

Comment: And how could it not be typedef char? (well, typedef signed char, maybe). Any other platform defines it somewhat different?